# Android sensor sampling rate drops in the background. Gaps as large as 10 minutes

Tags: android, performance, sensors, android-sensors

I have built a library that fuses the sensors on an Android device to determine some standard human behaviors. I use a Foreground service which raises the priority of my process (IE more cpu cycles) and should tell the system to not kill the app (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground). The foreground service should keep the process in a high priority and the app is not being killed either (I have verified).

It works well for a while but eventually, after 10s of minutes or a few hours, while in the background there will be gaps in sensor data. As low as a minute to as much as 10 minutes.

I am collecting all the sensors and sending it to a library for analysis at 32 hertz using java executors but we get varying degrees of success and outright failure on some devices. I would like suggestions as to why this might be happening and suggested optimizations... I REALLY appreciate it.

Thanks all!

Jared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if that could be your particular case, but some OEM devices just do similar things if I recall correctly.

Here is a list of suggestions how I would try to investigate:

1. Can you verify that the device does not go to sleep (or doze)?
2. Is the behavior the same while charging those devices?
3. Do you use [HW based queue](https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/batching.html) for event batching if available?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @simekadam - Comments inline
    1. Can you verify that the device does not go to sleep (or doze)? - Yes as we are testing devices pre "M" so doze is not an issue. Perhaps sleeping would be an issue. How do I tell if it's "sleeping"?
    2. Is the behavior the same while charging those devices? - Will test and get back to you.
    3. Do you use HW based queue for event batching if available? - yes.

Comment: @JaredSheehan acquiring a partial wakelock should keep your device awake. If you are already doing so, then it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Thanks @simekadam - In fact I did that last night (Partial Wake lock) and will have our sensor team analyze it. We had wake locks in before but they drained to much battery. Will let you know our results.

Comment: Wake locks significantly helped with the sampling rate and reduced the gaps. So accepting this answer, thanks @simekadam